# Return from flask not as expected

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a flask that links to a database, using a RESTapi. It is working to a certain degree. However, the format is not coming out correctly when I test a curl command to the internal server.

When running:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/Stocks
```

I expect to get a flat return such as:

> {"Name": "XYZ Corp", "Price": 123.23, "Stock": "XYZ", "id": 1}

However, I get:

> {
>
> "Name": "XYZ Corp",
>
> "Price": 123.23,
>
> "Stock": "XYZ",
>
> "id": 1
>
> }

I have used the following code to try and get the return to be flat, but it doesn't seem to work correctly:

```py
# StocksDAO
def findById(self, id):
    cursor = self.db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Stocks where id = %s"
    values = (id,)

    cursor.execute(sql, values)
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    return self.convert_Res(result)

# ..........

def convert_Res(self, result):
    colNames = ["id", "Stock", "Name", "Price"]
    item = {}

    if result:
        for i, colName in enumerate(colNames):
            value = result[i]
            item[colName] = value
    return item
```

Any suggestions on how to get the code to generate a flat return?

Edit: the Flask code for the sections above is:

```py
#!flask/bin/python

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, abort, make_response
from flask_cors import CORS
from Stocks_DB import stocksDAO

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="", static_folder=".")
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)

@app.route("/")

@app.route("/Stocks/<int:id>")
def getById(id):
    sel_stock = stocksDAO.findById(id)
    return jsonify(sel_stock)
```

Comment: Where is the flask route that `/Stocks` resolves to?

Comment: Sorry, added additional information for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`jsonify`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify) DOCs

> This function’s response will be pretty printed if the JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR config parameter is set to True or the Flask app is running in debug mode. Compressed (not pretty) formatting currently means no indents and no spaces after separators.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the link